# Can a phosphodiester bond form between RNA and DNA?

Tags: molecular-biology, dna, rna

In the initiation of DNA synthesis:

> the RNA segments are first synthesized by primase and then elongated
>   by DNA polymerase (Wikipedia).

What does 'elongated' mean in this context? Is it possible for RNA and DNA to form a phosphodiester bond to make a single strand which is part RNA and then part DNA?

Comment: A biochemistry book, such as Berg *et al.* online, is far better than Wikipedia. Your question is answered in [section 27.4.1](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK22587/#_A3796_) — see Figure 27.26. Try other books on the NCBI Bookshelf searching for Okazaki fragments.

Comment: @David thank you very much David , I've read the section 27.4.1 and the figure 27.26 but a bit unsure about it. It mean that a RNA and DNA can forms a sugar backbone bond between them to make a single strand RNA-DNA ?. I used to think that the RNA cannot forming bond with DNA like that and I was wrong. Thank you again!

Comment: The problem is not forming a phosphodiester bond between ribose and deoxyribose (chemically the same) but that one would expect a DNA polymerase to discriminate against the 3'OH of the ribose. You are in good company being surprised that it happens — it was an unexpected discovery at the time. I suspect that some component of the DNA polymerization process confers this changed specificity, but it is not my field and I haven't time to check this. If anyone knows the details I suggest they formulate them into a more comprehensive answer.